# Search and Replace Serialized DB Dump

Tags: sql, regex, database, serialization

I am moving a database from one server to an other and have lots of serialized data in there. So, I am wondering:

Is it possible to use `regex` to replace all occurrences like the following (and similar)

```
s:22:\"http://somedomain.com/\"  
s:26:\"http://somedomain.com/abc/\" 
s:29:\"http://somedomain.com/abcdef/\"
```

to

```
s:27:\"http://someOtherdomain.com/\"  
s:31:\"http://someOtherdomain.com/abc/\"  
s:34:\"http://someOtherdomain.com/abcdef/\"
```

Answer (score 1):

If that column, that holds these data, is of the same length, and these occurrences `22, 26, 29,...` are at the same position from the beginning of the string. Then, for SQL Server, you can use [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) ,  [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) with [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258228%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to do that:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @sub INT;
SET @s = 's:27:\"http://somedomain.com/\"';
SET @sub = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(':', @s) + 1, 2));
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, 'somedomain', 'someOtherdomain'), @sub, @sub + 5);
```

So `s:number:\"http://somedomain.com/\"` will become `s:number + 5:\"http://someOtherdomain.com/\"`.

If you want to run an `UPDATE` against that table you can write it this way:

```
UPDATE @t 
SET s = REPLACE(REPLACE(s, 'somedomain', 'someOtherdomain'), 
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(s, CHARINDEX(':', s) + 1, 2)),
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(s, CHARINDEX(':', s) + 1, 2)) + 5);
```

What does this query do, is that, it searches for the occurrence of `somedomain` and replaces it with `someOtherdomain`, get the number between the first two `:`'s, convert it to `INT` and replace it with the same number  `+ 5`. The following is how your data should looks like after you run the previous query:

```
s:27:\"http://someOtherdomain.com/\"
s:31:\"http://someOtherdomain.com/abc/\"
s:34:\"http://someOtherdomain.com/abcdef/\"
```

### Here is a [**Live Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80128/sql-search-and-replace).

Comment: THANKS! Ideally I would like to run this as pure regex on the raw sql, as there are also over 50 tables affected.